# BackgroundWorker not found

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, backgroundworker

I am using the System.componentmodel referance in a windows phone 8.1 to get the BackgroundWorker but each time i put the BackgroundWorker it gives me

**Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'BackgroundWorker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  HealthBand  C:\Users\husam\Desktop\Projects\HealthBand\HealthBand\ConnectionManager.cs  16**

I tried adding the referance but it says it is already added
and when i put

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

it says using directive is unnecessary

here is my code

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HealthBand
{
/// <summary>
/// Class to control the bluetooth connection to the Arduino.
/// </summary>
public class ConnectionManager
{
    private BackgroundWorker dataReadWorker;
    /// <summary>
    /// Socket used to communicate with Arduino.
    /// </summary>
    private StreamSocket socket;

    /// <summary>
    /// DataWriter used to send commands easily.
    /// </summary>
    private DataWriter dataWriter;

    /// <summary>
    /// DataReader used to receive messages easily.
    /// </summary>
    private DataReader dataReader;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thread used to keep reading data from socket.
    /// </summary>


    /// <summary>
    /// Delegate used by event handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message received.</param>
    public delegate void MessageReceivedHandler(string message);

    /// <summary>
    /// Event fired when a new message is received from Arduino.
    /// </summary>
    public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the manager, should be called in OnNavigatedTo of main page.
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
        socket = new StreamSocket();
        dataReadWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        dataReadWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        dataReadWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ReceiveMessages);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finalize the connection manager, should be called in OnNavigatedFrom of main page.
    /// </summary>
    public void Terminate()
    {
        if (socket != null)
        {
            socket.Dispose();
        }
        if (dataReadWorker != null)
        {
            dataReadWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to the given host device.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceHostName">The host device name.</param>
    public async void Connect(HostName deviceHostName)
    {
        if (socket != null)
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(deviceHostName, "1");
            dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
            dataReadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Receive messages from the Arduino through bluetooth.
    /// </summary>
    private async void ReceiveMessages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Read first byte (length of the subsequent message, 255 or less). 
                uint sizeFieldCount = await dataReader.LoadAsync(1);
                if (sizeFieldCount != 1)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }

                // Read the message. 
                uint messageLength = dataReader.ReadByte();
                uint actualMessageLength = await dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLength);
                if (messageLength != actualMessageLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }
                // Read the message and process it.
                string message = dataReader.ReadString(actualMessageLength);
                MessageReceived(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send command to the Arduino through bluetooth.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">The sent command.</param>
    /// <returns>The number of bytes sent</returns>
    public async Task<uint> SendCommand(string command)
    {
        uint sentCommandSize = 0;
        if (dataWriter != null)
        {
            uint commandSize = dataWriter.MeasureString(command);
            dataWriter.WriteByte((byte)commandSize);
            sentCommandSize = dataWriter.WriteString(command);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        }
        return sentCommandSize;
    }
}
}
```

Please what can I do to fix this error

Comment: From what is written [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.95).aspx), *BackgroundWorker* is only suppored in Windows Phone for WP7.0 and WP7.1.

Comment: isn't there any way to workaround it or modify the code to make it work

Answer (score 3):

*BackgroundWorker* is not supported in WP8.1. Instead of using it, redirect your work to *ThreadPool* with *Task.Run* method. As the article [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_Threads) says:

> The async-based approach to asynchronous programming is preferable to existing approaches in almost every case. In particular, this approach is better than BackgroundWorker for IO-bound operations because the code is simpler and you don't have to guard against race conditions. In combination with Task.Run, async programming is better than BackgroundWorker for CPU-bound operations because async programming separates the coordination details of running your code from the work that Task.Run transfers to the threadpool.

For some more healp, code samples and comparison, visit [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Comment: The code is not working can any one help in converting it to Task.Run code

Comment: @HossamFuad Try to convert your `ReceiveMessages` to *Task* and instead of starting worker `dataReadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();` put `await Task.Run(ReceiveMessages)`. How have you tried to convert it?

Comment: @HossamFuad As you also use cancellation, then [this pattern](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-4.html) also should help.

Comment: i am trying to figure this out but i am new to this type of code so please help me further

Comment: @HossamFuad I don't believe I could have explained it better that Stephen had on his blog. It's also hard to help further without seeing what you have tried and knowing how your app should behave.